# Userform stops other sheets from scrolling

Tags: vba, excel

I have a few userforms. One is a popup that shows instructions and another is for entering quantities. Problem is when I click one and close it (each closes with `Unload Me`) then when I switch sheets with a `sht.Activate` macro button that sheet won't scroll. Looks like the sheet is frozen. I can fix the problem by loading the userform and closing it again on the current sheet to "Unfreeze" the sheet.

Any idea why this is happening?

> UserForm

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Below is how I call it from a button.

```
Sub Instructions()
With UserFormInstructions
    .StartUpPosition = 0
    .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
    .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
    .Show
End With
End Sub
```

> Sheet Button

```
Sub goto630()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Foundation Plates")
Dim sht3 As Worksheet
Set sht3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("630 BOM")

sht3.Activate
sht3.Unprotect

sht2.Visible = True
sht3.Visible = True

On Error GoTo 0

    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 90
    ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = True
    ActiveWindow.DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = True
    ActiveWindow.DisplayVerticalScrollBar = True
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
    sht3.DisplayPageBreaks = False

sht2.Protect
sht3.Protect _
        DrawingObjects:=False, _
        Contents:=True, _
        Scenarios:=False, _
        UserInterFaceOnly:=False, _
        AllowFormattingCells:=True
Call NoSelect

Set sht3 = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub NoSelect()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToLeft:=4

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like some combination of screenupdating and your sheet being protected. Instead of using `.Protect` and `.Unprotect` just protect the sheet in `Workbook_Open` and use the `UserInterfaceOnly:= True` option instead.

Comment: I know you are resetting it to `True` in button code but still try this for me... In the `UserForm_QueryClose` event of the userform, put this `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` Now try it

Comment: what is the modal property set to for your form?

Comment: @braX Modal is set to False, Tried True but still same result